# Criar relatorios em Angular e Firebase

Tags: html, firebase, typescript, relatório, angular

### O que usar para criar relatórios com Angular e Firebase?

Tenho uma aplicação na área de saúde com Angular e Firebase, estou chegando na parte de relatórios do sistema e gostaria de alternativas na criação de relatórios.

**Os relatórios devem:**

1. Ser exibidos online dentro do sistema e com a opção de imprimir.
2. Ser baixado em PDF para arquivar e se necessário imprimir também.

Gostaria de saber o que posso utilizar para formar relatórios com Angular e Firebase, andei fazendo umas pesquisas mas nada me agradou de tal forma, pois gostaria de algo que fosse mais rápido para desenvolvimento.

Answer (score 1):

Tinha uma aplicação com angular e firebase tambem mas era um PDV
imprimia os pedidos da seguinte forma tinha uma classe ou modelo para cada tipo de pedido nessa classe tinha dois metodos um para desenhar o html que ia ser impresso e a outra para chamar a janela de impressão:

```
// relatorioPrinter.model.ts

export class RelatorioPrinter {
   public impressao: string;

   constructor(dados: any) {
       this.paint(dados);
   }

   public print(): void {
       const params = [
          '', 
          '_blank', 
          'height=ALTURA_DO PDF,width=LARGURA_DO_PDF'
       ]

       const popup = window.open(...params);

       popup.document.open();
       popup.document.write(this.impressao);
       popup.document.close();
   }

   public paint(dados: any): void {
       this.impressao = `<!DOCTYPE html>
                      <html>
                        <head>
                           <style>
                           /* SEU ESTILO AQUI */
                           </style>
                        </head>
                        <body onload="window.print()">`;

        this.impressao += `SEU HTML AQUI ${dados.SEUS_DADOS_AQUI}`;
        this.impressao += '</body></html>';
   }
}
```

Para usar era simples:

```
// exemplo.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RelatorioPrinter } from 'app/models/relatorioPrinter';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-exemplo',
    templateUrl: './exemplo.component.html'
 })
 export class ExemploComponent {
    public printer: RelatorioPrinter; 

    public constructor() { 
        const seuDados = {};
        this.printer = new RelatorioPrinter(seuDados);
    }
 }
```

Bom depois precisei de um solução mais robusta para compactar muitos relatorios etc.. mas de inicio isso me ajudou bastante.

Espero ter ajudado :D

Comment: @Luiz Aceite esta resposta (clicando no símbolo "certo") se ela responde a sua questão, para que os outros saibam que o seu problema foi resolvido.